# ¿Como creo un servicio con systemd para un socket levantado con python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, ubuntu, socket

estoy realizando un proyecto donde requiero utilizar un socket y dejarlo corriendo en segundo plano y recurrir a ***systemd***, el cual lo he utilizado para otros proyectos donde requiero procesos en segundo plano.

Sin embargo, no he logrado configurar un servicio para un socket que levanto con **python3** utilizando **systemd** he intentado realizando la configuración con socket sencillo, pero sin ningún éxito.

**Servidor de Ejemplo**

```
import socket 
host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 9999
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024 

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as socket_tcp:
    socket_tcp.bind((host, port)) 
    socket_tcp.listen(5) # Esperamos la conexión del cliente 
    conn, addr = socket_tcp.accept() # Establecemos la conexión con el cliente 
    with conn:
        print('[*] Conexión establecida') 
        while True:
            # Recibimos bytes, convertimos en str
            data = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
            # Verificamos que hemos recibido datos
            if not data:
                break
            else:
                print('[*] Datos recibidos: {}'.format(data.decode('utf-8'))) 
            conn.send(data) # Hacemos echo convirtiendo de nuevo a bytes
```

**Cliente de Ejemplo**

```
import socket
# El cliente debe tener las mismas especificaciones del servidor
host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 9999
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024
MESSAGE = 'Hola, mundo!' # Datos que queremos enviar
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as socket_tcp:
    socket_tcp.connect((host, port))
    # Convertimos str a bytes
    socket_tcp.send(MESSAGE.encode('utf-8'))
    data = socket_tcp.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
```

**Configuración de UNIT File y creación de servicio**

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/socket_prueba.service
sudo rm -r /etc/systemd/system/socket_prueba.service
[Unit]
Description= Server Relay System: Manager
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/pipenv run python /path/test_server.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable socket_prueba.service
sudo systemctl start socket_prueba.service
sudo systemctl status socket_prueba.service
```

Cuando comprobé el estado del servicio, el resultado fue el siguiente:

```
● socket_prueba.service - Server Relay System: Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/socket_prueba.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2021-09-25 16:07:17 -05; 58min ago
    Process: 25771 ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/pipenv run python 

/home/path>
   Main PID: 25771 (code=exited, status=2)

sep 25 16:07:17 serversaas systemd[1]: socket_prueba.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is >
sep 25 16:07:17 serversaas systemd[1]: Stopped Server Relay System: Manager.
sep 25 16:07:17 serversaas systemd[1]: socket_prueba.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
sep 25 16:07:17 serversaas systemd[1]: socket_prueba.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
sep 25 16:07:17 serversaas systemd[1]: Failed to start Server Relay System: Manager.
```

También me guie de este ejemplo, lo único que no lo coloqué la carpeta tmp, lo cual pienso que no debería generar problemas el cual levanto el servicio, pero cuando utilicé el cliente para probar el servidor tenía el siguiente error cuando comprobé el estado
[systemd python3](https://gist.github.com/drmalex07/333d8a88c4918954e8e4)

```
[socket con python y systemd][1]
● socket_prueba.socket - Socket prueba
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/socket_prueba.socket; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: service-start-limit-hit) since Sat 2021-09-25 17:00:47 -05; 4s ago
   Triggers: ● socket_prueba.service
     Listen: 127.0.0.1:9999 (Stream)

sep 25 17:00:47 vidm-OMEN systemd[1]: Listening on Socket prueba.
sep 25 17:00:47 vidm-OMEN systemd[1]: socket_prueba.socket: Failed with result 'service-start-limit-hit'.
```